# Using Hashicorp Vault and Spring Cloud in different environments

Tags: spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

We are using vault to get rid of all secrets from our codebase and config servers. Vault aws auth with its secure introduction seems like the perfect fit for this. However our dev environment is not on aws and vault cannot work with config server to fetch different [configurations per environment](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/342).

Do you guys see a way out where I could still use the aws auth for staging and prod and a different auth for dev?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication methods can be configured via `bootstrap.properties` so ideally have multiple profiles, one of them to use AWS authentication and the other one for dev.